# Taking values from string to array

Tags: php, text

Is it possible take a value from a STRING like:

```
$string = ' * some parameter: A+ * Nextparameter: 0,671 kWh/24h * 
        Some another parameter value: 245 kWh/year * Last parm: 59 kg';
```

Now i know what parameters i need and a have a list:

My parameters what I'm finding (always will be the same):

```
$parm1 = "* some parameter:";
$parm2 = "* Nextparameter:";
$parm3 = "* Some another parameter value:";
$parm4 = "* Last parm:";
```

How can I get this result:

```
$parm1result = "A+";
.. etc ...
```

Or, the best way:

```
$result = array(
    "some parameter" => "A+",
    "Nextparameter" => "0.671", 
    ... etc ...
);
```

Thank you ...

Comment: COuld be great if you have a separator like "&", any other way you need to use regular expresion for match any value that you need

Comment: If you're not after a truly generic solution I think the easiest way would be to `explode` on `"*"` and `explode` each part of that operation on `":"` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, last post got screwed up.

You need to split twice and apply some trimming:

```
<?php
$string = ' * some parameter: A+ * Nextparameter: 0,671 kWh/24h *
    Some another parameter value: 245 kWh/year * Last parm: 59 kg';

// remove beginning and ending stars and whitespace so we don't have empty values
$string = trim($string, ' *');

// get parameters
$arr = explode('*', $string);

// trim a little more
$arr = array_map(trim, $arr);

// add stuff to array
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $param) {
  // nicer way of representing an array of 2 values
  list($key, $value) = explode(':', $param);
  $result[trim($key)] = trim($value);
}
var_export($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an additional way of retrieving the parameters into an array, you can use the `preg_match_all()` function.

However, this might be the more complex (although shorter) way to do it:

```
$params = array();
$string = ' * some parameter: A+ * Nextparameter: 0,671 kWh/24h * Some another parameter value: 245 kWh/year * Last parm: 59 kg';
if (preg_match_all('/\*\s*([^\:]+):([^\*]+)/', $string, $m) > 0) {
    foreach ($m[1] as $index => $matches) {
        $params[trim($matches)] = trim($m[2][$index]);
    }
}

// $params now contains the parameters and values.
```